# how can i get weighted finite automaton?

Tags: finite-automata, automata

[image]

1.how can i get this automaton(non blocking and weighted)?

2.I want to see some simple examples.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: i just want to see a state diagram or transition system for a simple example. that's mean if some automaton is given, then how can i construct weigthed finite automaton in the figure. please help me. T,.T

Answer (score 0):

Your original automaton is already a weighted one as stated in the problem. The new one adds to it loops for every letter in every state. Further it gives weight 0 to all the original transitions and a weight to the new ones that is not understandable from the information you give (what is \psi_{i,j}?).

You formally get this automaton by simply aplying the definitions you provide on the original automaton.

For example: original automaton over alphabet {a,b}, states {q (initial), p (final)}, transitions: (q, a, p) weight 1, (p, b, p) weight 2. In the new automaton you get (q, a, p) weight 0 and (p, b, p) with the weight that cannot be understood from your definitions. Further you get the new transitions (q, a, q), (q, b, q), and (p, a, p).